# Mod!Harry Potter and the multiverse

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Fic where Harry is the master of death and travels the multiverse helping out other main characters and getting a large harem of lovers to make his dream of a large family come true?

Comment: What's with the `Mod!` prefix in the title?

Comment: @11.01.11: It's a an abbreviation for stories where Harry is the Master Of Death.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Still needs better clarification. And, what's with your last edit?

Comment: The lack of a space is the syntax. Mod!Harry, Evil!Harry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be "[A MODern Man](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10191828/1/A-MODern-Man)" by dogbertcarroll

> "If you're really curious on how things could have turned out differently you could take the place of one of your dead alternates," Luna suggested.
>
> "Pardon?" Harry asked.
>
> "You're the Master of Death," Luna pointed out. "That means more than just a nifty title. You can take the place of one of the infinite alternate versions of you that have passed on."
>
> "You mean like alternate realities?"
>
> "Exactly," Luna agreed. "Simply concentrate on your connection to the Hallows and feel for the life you want and then decide to make the switch."
>
> Harry wondered if it could truly be that easy as he closed his eyes and imagined it his form fading into a ghostly outline before flickering out.
>
> Lune stared wide eyed. "But… I was just fucking with you!"

I've read a few of dogbertcarroll's other stories, so the "Mod!Harry" bit struck me.